# Python script for generating SVG wireframe spheres

Tags: python, math, svg

I'm trying to write a function in python, which produces SVG images similar as the following:

[image: Example result]

I'd like to avoid using numpy or similar matrix libraries and just stick to basic math functions like sin, cos, sqrt, pi etc.

I managed to draw points on a sphere by using the following steps:

- Generate polar coordinates for several points by keeping the same radius, and different angles.
- Convert them to Cartesian coordinates
- Translate them to move the center of the sphere away from the origin
- Project the 3d points onto a plane at the origin
- Scale the points to fit the viewBox of the svg
- Write out the svg code using a small circle object for each point.

Here is the code in python I used to do this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from math import sin, cos, sqrt, radians

SPHERE_CENTER=(0,0,50)
SPHERE_RADIUS=60
POINT_SPACING=30
Z_SCALE=0.4

def generate_sphere_polar(radius):
    results = []
    for a in range(360//POINT_SPACING):
        for b in range(180//POINT_SPACING):
            results.append((radius, radians(b*POINT_SPACING), radians(a*POINT_SPACING)))

    return results

def pol2cart(pcoord):
    x = pcoord[0] * sin(pcoord[1]) * cos(pcoord[2])
    z = pcoord[0] * sin(pcoord[1]) * sin(pcoord[2])
    y = pcoord[0] * cos(pcoord[1])

    return x, y, z * Z_SCALE

def translate(coord, d):
    return coord[0] + d[0], coord[1] + d[1], coord[2] + d[2]

def project(coord):
    return coord[0] / coord[2], coord[1] / coord[2]

def mapFromTo(x, a, b, c, d):
    return (x - a) / (b - a) * (d - c) + c

def points_to_svg(points):
    svg = '<html><body><svg width="100mm" height="100mm" viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1">\n'
    for point in points:
        svg += point_to_svg(point)

    svg += '</svg></body></html>'

    return svg

def point_to_svg(point):
    spoint = project(point)
    x = mapFromTo(spoint[0], -3, 3, 0, 100)
    y = mapFromTo(spoint[1], -3, 3, 0, 100)

    return '<circle cx="%.2f" cy="%.2f" r="0.5" fill="#000000" />' % (x, y)

def draw_svg_sphere(radius, center):
    ppoints = generate_sphere_polar(radius)
    cpoints = []
    for ppoint in ppoints:
        cpoints.append(translate(pol2cart(ppoint), center))

    return points_to_svg(cpoints)

if __name__ == "__main__": print(draw_svg_sphere(SPHERE_RADIUS, SPHERE_CENTER))
```

Here is the result:

```html
<html><body><svg width="100mm" height="100mm" viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1">
<circle cx="50.00" cy="70.00" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="60.00" cy="67.32" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="67.32" cy="60.00" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="70.00" cy="50.00" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="67.32" cy="40.00" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="60.00" cy="32.68" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="50.00" cy="70.00" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="57.73" cy="65.46" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="62.42" cy="58.28" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="63.97" cy="50.00" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="62.42" cy="41.72" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="57.73" cy="34.54" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="50.00" cy="70.00" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="54.14" cy="64.34" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="56.37" cy="57.35" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="57.06" cy="50.00" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="56.37" cy="42.65" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="54.14" cy="35.66" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="50.00" cy="70.00" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="50.00" cy="63.97" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="50.00" cy="57.06" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="50.00" cy="50.00" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="50.00" cy="42.94" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="50.00" cy="36.03" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="50.00" cy="70.00" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="45.86" cy="64.34" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="43.63" cy="57.35" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="42.94" cy="50.00" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="43.63" cy="42.65" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="45.86" cy="35.66" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="50.00" cy="70.00" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="42.27" cy="65.46" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="37.58" cy="58.28" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="36.03" cy="50.00" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="37.58" cy="41.72" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="42.27" cy="34.54" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="50.00" cy="70.00" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="40.00" cy="67.32" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="32.68" cy="60.00" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="30.00" cy="50.00" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="32.68" cy="40.00" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="40.00" cy="32.68" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="50.00" cy="70.00" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="40.16" cy="69.68" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="31.06" cy="62.62" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="27.21" cy="50.00" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="31.06" cy="37.38" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="40.16" cy="30.32" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="50.00" cy="70.00" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="43.69" cy="71.87" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="36.47" cy="65.62" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="32.89" cy="50.00" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="36.47" cy="34.38" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="43.69" cy="28.13" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="50.00" cy="70.00" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="50.00" cy="72.79" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="50.00" cy="67.11" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="50.00" cy="50.00" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="50.00" cy="32.89" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="50.00" cy="27.21" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="50.00" cy="70.00" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="56.31" cy="71.87" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="63.53" cy="65.62" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="67.11" cy="50.00" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="63.53" cy="34.38" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="56.31" cy="28.13" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="50.00" cy="70.00" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="59.84" cy="69.68" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="68.94" cy="62.62" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="72.79" cy="50.00" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="68.94" cy="37.38" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /><circle cx="59.84" cy="30.32" r="0.5" fill="#000000" /></svg></body></html>
```

How can I draw lines between these points to create the curvature, as well as rotate the entire sphere while only showing the front facing lines (not the hidden ones)?

Answer (score 0):

I would generate quadrilateral polygons (or triangles at the poles) and use [back-face culling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-face_culling) to decide which ones to draw (it works only on closed, convex, objects, but spheres are both, so...).